# Regex to capture all but the last hashtag

Tags: regex

I normally sling regexes like it's a native language, but I'm stumped by this puzzle today. I need to capture all the text of a string except for the final hashtag. Any hashtags except for the final one should be included, and it also needs to match if there are no hashtags at all.

Test Case 1:

- Input: `Foo bar #baz`
- Match: `Foo bar`

Test Case 2:

- Input: `Foo bar #baz #qux`
- Match: `Foo bar #baz`

Test Case 3:

- Input: `Foo bar`
- Match: `Foo bar`

Because of the environment I'm using this in (Zapier), I have a tight constraint that I need the matching string in a single capturing group with the same group number regardless of the case. Zapier uses the Python engine, FWIW.

The context is posting photos from Instagram automatically to Twitter, but needing to limit the length to 280 characters. Since Zapier's truncate function doesn't allow cutting on clean word boundaries, there's the chance that 280 characters could run out in the middle of a hashtag, potentially leading to an embarassing result when Twitter auto-links it. (Zapier's truncate does allow appending an ellipsis, which mitigates the issue for regular words.) Since it's not critical to include every hashtag, I want to throw away the final one, in case it's been truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an unrolled loop method.
This is probably the fastest way to do it.

`[^#]*(?:\#(?![^#]*$)[^#]*)*`

see https://regex101.com/r/vlEows/1/tests

Comment: This is great! Nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just about as soon as I finished typing this out, I found my own solution (yay, rubber-ducking  it). Figured I'd post it for anybody else needing this specific strange solution:

```regex
((^[^#]+$)|(?:.|\n)+)(?(2)|\s#[^#]+)
```

Test results: https://regex101.com/r/RNGVSL/2/tests

**Update**

Simpler answer from Wiktor Stribiżew in comments:

```regex
(?s)^(.*?)(?:\s*#[^\s#]+)?$
```

Test results: https://regex101.com/r/RNGVSL/3/tests

Comment: Never use `(?:.|\n)+`. Use `.` with an appropriate modifier, `(?s)` (`m` in Ruby, etc.). Or, if you do not have access to modifiers, `[\w\W]` instead of a dot. Alternation will cause redundant backtracking.

Comment: Also, why not `(?s)^(.*?)(?:\s*#[^\s#]+)?$` and grab Group 1  value? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5hTHB1/1).

Comment: I don't have access to modifiers in Zapier, or else I would have used `s`. However, good suggestion with `[\w\W]`. Your simplification doesn't work because there may be newlines in the original text that need to be preserved. I just didn't note that in original question for simplicity. Seems like this is the winner so far: `((^[^#]+$)|[\w\W]+)(?(2)|\s#[^#]+)`.

Comment: You edited your comment while I was replying. Checking out your new version now...

Comment: It is the same comment. `(?s)^(.*?)(?:\s*#[^\s#]+)?$`. I just added the `s` inline modifier. You do not need `[\w\W]` in Python regex in this scenario.

Comment: Hmm, yes, by putting the modifier inline, that works. Wasn't familiar with that syntax (Python is not my normal language). Will update answer.

Comment: Though, technically according to Regex101, that's actually less efficient at 2098 steps vs.  655 for my original one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could match the following regular expression, which conditions on whether the string ends with a hashtag.

```
^(?:(?=.*#\w+$).*(?=#\w+$)|.*)
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/J5fJM4/1/)

If you need a capture group, use `$0`, which holds the complete match.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^              : match beginning of string
(?:            : begin non-capture group
  (?=.*#\w+$)  : positive lookahead asserts that the string
                 ends with a hashtag
  .*           : match 0+ characters
  (?=#\w+$)    : positive lookahead asserts that the next character
                 begins a hashtag at the end of the string
|              : or
  .*           : match 0+ characters
)              : end non-capture group
```

One could alternatively remove the non-capture group and repeat the beginning-of-string anchor:

```
^(?=.*#\w+$).*(?=#\w+$)|^.*
```